# Discord bot recognize if someone pings an account and replies

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been working on a basic discord bot to reply when someone pings my account. So far it works only for direct pings and not for when you ping my role. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
const ownerId = "";

client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.mentions.has(ownerId)) {
        message.reply(`reply`);
    };
});
```

Comment: What is `ownerId`? A role ID or a user ID?

Comment: ownerId is a user ID for my main account. This is what i want the bot to respond to

Comment: Is `ownerId` being empty intentional for the post?

Comment: Yeah, i removed it for the post

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea in the code below is that it'll first grab the `GuildMember` object from the user in the Guild that the message was sent in. Then, it'll check the message for any mentions and place all of the role IDs in `messageRoles`. It also places all of the user's member roles into another array called `memberRoles`. Then, it compares the two arrays together with `some` (very handy method), and if it's true, then it'll reply back.

Code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
const ownerId = "";

client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.mentions.has(ownerId)) {
        message.reply(`reply`);
    }

    let user = client.users.cache.get(ownerId);
    let currentGuild = message.guild;
    let currentMember = currentGuild.members.cache.get(user.id);
    let memberRoles = [];
    currentMember.roles.cache.each(role => {
        memberRoles.push(role.id);
    });
    let messageRoles = [];
    console.log(message.mentions.roles);
    
    message.mentions.roles.each(role => {
        messageRoles.push(role.id);
    })
    let containsMention = messageRoles.some(x => memberRoles.includes(x));
    if (containsMention) {
        message.reply('reply');
    }
});
```

Comment: This would mean i have to add roleIds for all the roles im part of. Is there any way for the bot to recognize who pings me including direct and role pings?

Comment: I've updated the code with the accompanying explanation. That should help.